# How to use a getX or getY method in java?

Tags: java, get

I have found a lot of helpful stuff for how to use a getX or getY but none of them have helped me with the code I was using.

I want to get the x and y position of a rectangle every time it moves but I am not sure how. Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(posY == 0){
        posX = posX + speed;
    }
    if((posX <= 0)&&(posY != 0)){
        posX = posX + speed - speed;
        posY = posY + speedY;
    }
    if(posX >= 600 - x){
        posX = posX + speed - speed;
        posY = posY + speedY;       
    }
    if(posY >= y - halfY){
        posX = posX - speed;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

I believe the problem is that `actionPerformed()` is a void but I am not sure how to get the posx and posy and use it anywhere in my class while still keeping `actionPerformed` as a void because I need to to keep the program working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code implies that you already **have** fields `posX` and `posY` that represent the position of your rectangle.

Your `actionPerformed()` method is already updating those; so every time this method is invoked, the rectangle will probably move ... and the **fields** within your class get updated.

In other words: you already got that data within your object! And if that doesn't help you have to show us **more** code.

Beyond that: if you have trouble understanding such *basic* things, then I recommend you to **stop** working on UI programs for a while. UI programming is an advanced topic; but you seem to have troubles with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

posX and posY should be members of your class. Everytime the actionPerformed is called, you set their value. Then you can use it in your other functions.